# Spring batch couchbase

Tags: spring-data, spring-batch, couchbase

I would like to create a reader for a spring batch, reading from my couchbase database using Spring Data.

Any ideas ?

My actual reader :

```java
@Bean
public RepositoryItemReader<Product> reader() {
    LOGGER.info("Creating reader for Couchbase");
    RepositoryItemReader<Product> repositoryItemReader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
    repositoryItemReader.setRepository(productRepository);
    repositoryItemReader.setMethodName("findBySource");
    repositoryItemReader.setPageSize(1000);
    Map<String, Sort.Direction> sort = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> parameters = new ArrayList();
    String source = "SOMESTRING";
    parameters.add(source);
    repositoryItemReader.setArguments(parameters);
    sort.put("field1", Sort.Direction.ASC);
    repositoryItemReader.setSort(sort);
    return repositoryItemReader;
}
```

findBySource method is a custom repository method (through spring data) using a query ending by a Pageable paramerter as indicated in documentation.

I know that a pull request has been created (BATCH-2275: added support to read/write from/to Couchbase #5) to do so but using Views which is not my case.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is your issue/error?

Comment: The reader can't use a custom repository method for a simple reason : this method should take as final paramter a Pageable. If I create my own repository method using N1QL (with  @Query), the reader will never reconize it. So I created my own reader extending AbstractPaginatedDataItemReader which working fine.